# Undefined function or variable 'addframe'

Tags: matlab

```
 clear all
 close all

 mov=VideoWriter('mult.avi');

 N=50;
 om=0.1;
 X = linspace(0,12.4,N);
 Y = 0*X;
 Z2= 0*X;

 for it=1:100

 Z = cos(X-it*om);
 Y2= cos(X-it*om);

 stem3(X,Y,Z,'r','fill')
 hold on
 stem3(X,Y2,Z2,'k','fill')
 hold on;
 line(X,Y,Z2);

 for ix=1:N
  hold on;
  plot([X(ix) X(ix)],[0 Y2(ix)],'k');
 end;

 hold off
 view(-25,30);

 xlim([X(1) X(end)]);
 ylim([-1 1])
 zlim([-1 1])

 set(gcf,'Color',[1 1 1],'nextplot','replacechildren', 'Visible','off')

 axis off

 FF=getframe(gcf);

 mov=addframe(mov,FF);
 end;


 mov=close(mov);
```

This is my matlab code. Everytime i hit run in command window i see this error

```
 Undefined function or variable 'addframe'.

 Error in EM (line 41)
 mov=addframe(mov,FF);
```

This file contains  electromagnetic wave as two components: electric and magnetic fields at right angles to each other and it supposed to move forward. But it stay still all the time  of course its because addframe error. So maybe someone could help me ?

Comment: Could you post sources of `addframe` function?

Comment: what source ? this is all i got :(

Comment: Where function `addframe` defined?

Comment: mov=addframe(mov,FF);
;

Comment: oh srr , so i did not defined it , i thought that its some native matlab function

Comment: but it suposed to be native like VideoWriter function u dont need to define it , am i wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code:

- if you use `VideoWriter` class you have to actually open the movie file (calling the `open` method) since `VideoWriter`only constructs a `VideoWriter object` to write video data to a compressed AVI file
- also, using `VideoWriter` you have to call the method `writeVideo` (instead of `addframe` (which is not a `VideoWriter` method
- then, at the end of the script (at the end of the registraion of the movie) you have to close the AVI file with the `close` method

The function `addframe` could be used to add frames to an `avifile object` created with the function `avifile`; notice that this function  will be removed in a future release.

Hereafter you can find the updated script.

```
clear all
close all

mov=VideoWriter('mult_1.avi');
% Added 
open(mov);

N=50;
om=0.1;
X = linspace(0,12.4,N);
Y = 0*X;
Z2= 0*X;

for it=1:100

   Z = cos(X-it*om);
   Y2= cos(X-it*om);

   stem3(X,Y,Z,'r','fill')
   hold on
   stem3(X,Y2,Z2,'k','fill')
   hold on;
   line(X,Y,Z2);

   for ix=1:N
      hold on;
      plot([X(ix) X(ix)],[0 Y2(ix)],'k');
   end;

   hold off
   view(-25,30);

   xlim([X(1) X(end)]);
   ylim([-1 1])
   zlim([-1 1])

   set(gcf,'Color',[1 1 1],'nextplot','replacechildren', 'Visible','off')

   axis off

   FF=getframe(gcf);
   % With "VideoWriter" use "writevideo" to add frames to the video
   writeVideo(mov,FF);

end;
% Close the video file
close(mov);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, can I ask one more question ? 
How to make this file opened instead of exporting after i press run ?

Comment: What do you mean with _make this file opened instead of exporting after i press run_? Notice, I've edited the answer and I've added few information about `addframe`: The function addframe could be used to add frames to an avifile object created with the function avifile; notice that this function will be removed in a future release.

Comment: It is not a stupid question! Simply I did not understand it, perhaps you might clarify it.